# DB2 Trigger OLD_TABLE dynamic columns

Tags: db2

I made an after update trigger which I intended to use as an audit log for changes to the primary record in source table. Everything is working as expected except when I view my trigger's definition I can see it resolved all columns for MYLIB.NMF00PAUDI and OTBL which means that I have to recreate this trigger for every column I add into source and audit tables.

Can I somehow retain SELECT *? This way I only need to modfiy source and audit tables.

```
CREATE TRIGGER MYLIB.NMF00PAUDIT
    AFTER UPDATE ON MYLIB.NMF00P 
    REFERENCING OLD_TABLE AS OTBL 
    FOR EACH ROW 
        MODE DB2SQL 
        BEGIN ATOMIC 
            INSERT INTO MYLIB . NMF00PAUDI
            SELECT * FROM OTBL
    ;
END
```

Becomes this when I view the definition:

```
BEGIN ATOMIC 
    INSERT INTO MYLIB . NMF00PAUDI (COL1, COL2, COL3)
    SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM OTBL
    ;
END
```

Comment: Have you tried changing source & audit table and what happens with your trigger? DB2 tracks dependencies between objects and rebinds/recompiles them if there are changes.

Answer (score 1):

Could you automate the creation of the trigger definition (either with a fancy text templating tool or even just a simple script) that could find the columns from sysibm.syscolumns and generate your trigger body using all the current columns?  Then any time the table schema changes you just re-generate the script and re-apply the trigger to cover the new field.

Comment: Great idea, I think it would be feasible. I now just use the same `CREATE TRIGGER` with a * (star) script and simply add a `DROP TRIGGER` in a step before the Create statement. I need to do it every time I change my source and audit tables, but I guess I'd need to do it with your proposed solution also.